# Prevent FragmentStatePagerAdapter to not destroy fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have some `Fragments` in a `List Collection` to be used for a `Viewpager` with a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Im using only `getItem(){return list.get(index;}` and `getCount(){return list.size()}` in it. If i wanna replace that List in the adapter, i load another List with different Fragments, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and set the adapter to the viewpager again to make it happen.
That is workin fine.

But if i do this fragmentset change the previous Fragments are gettin destroyed with a call of `onDestroy()` through the PagerAdapter. Now i would like to know if its possible to prevent the onDestroy call? Or i HAVE TO use `onSavedInstanceState()` to load the previous Fragments and their state again?

Im just searchin some different methods to restore the state of the fragments which are gone because of the change in the adapter. If anyone know something about this it would be nice to share some thoughts. I can give code if its necessary.

Maybe a good Info: I dont use the PagerAdapter to instantiate the Fragments. I do this before i load the Lists to the Adapter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Now i would like to know if its possible to prevent the onDestroy call?

The *complete and entire point* of using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` is to allow Android to destroy fragments that are not in use. You should be using `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead.

Comment: Thx for that info. Than i got the doc wrong because of the "..may be destroyed..". Ill try the FPA. I have reached my goal with the FSPA using the functions saveState() and restoreState().

Comment: @SteveBenett can you post your sample?

Answer (score 3):

I suggested same problem the ather day.

so I found another solution.

I override destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) in Adapter class.

and changed not working super.destroyItem ..

I'm not sure that solution is better solution, but it's definitely help for me.